# Moving background out of picture when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just tried out some effects including a moving background but when using the code below the background goes further and further up as you scroll down on a long page. Any suggestions as how to make it stop when it gets to get end of the image (if you know how I mean...). I don't want a white space to become visible when scrolling down.

```
body {
    background: url(/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-position:center;
    background-size: 110% 120%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').mousemove(function (e) {
            var x = -(e.pageX + this.offsetLeft) / 20;
            var y = -(e.pageY + this.offsetTop) / 20;
            $('body').css('background-position', (-3 + x) + 'px ' + (-3 + y) + 'px');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide link of this page or bg.jpg

Comment: Get the background image height first (BH), and window height(WH), then check for this condition : if((BH-WH)>e.pageY){ //do as u r doing}. Hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: @Dheeraj You should be able to use any image since the size is set to 110% and 120%.

Comment: @ManishPatwari You mean to compare it to? I just don't know what to compare it to exactly, since the height of the image can vary.

Comment: You have to get the image hight and then subtract it with the window height, and scroll the background till the difference height.

Comment: check this if u get some help. http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/jquery-parallax-scrolling/ –

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
html{ height:100%; width:100%;}
body {height:100%; width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
```

Comment: I already have those set except for the overflow: hidden which would take away my scroll bar completely. So no. :)